# Upload file to S3 from rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I would like to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket from a rails app. The file comes via a user uploading it. I am having difficulty finding the proper documentation for this because of the different versions of the aws-sdk. Additionally, the `acl: :public_read` is intentional. I only want authorized users uploading, but anyone should be able to access it.

My current problem is that I am *unable to index into a lazy loaded collection*. Google provides no useful information for how to not load it lazily.

Here is my relevant code. Note that the controller actions for `new` and `show` are empty for now.

## messages_controller.rb

```
  def create
    # Creates the file object
    obj = $S3.bucket(TEST_BUCKET).objects[params[:file].original_filename]

    # Uploads the file
    obj.write(
       file: params[:file],
       acl: :public_read
    )
  end
```

## new.html.erb

```
<h1>Upload a file</h1>

<%= form_tag messages_path, enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file  %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload file' %>
<% end %>
```

I am using restful routes so the only relevant routing info is   `resources :messages`

I am running rails 6.0.0beta, not that it should matter. I am using version 3 of the aws-sdk gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution sort of. I do not know how to solve the lazy loading problem but there is a better way.

In the create controller action

```
def create
  obj = $S3.bucket(TEST_BUCKET).object('key_name')
  obj.put(body: params[:file].to_io)
end
```

It'll take some more investigation to apply the attributes to it that I want but this should help anyone else scouring the 3! different versions of the sdk documentation.

The `.to_io` method on the file is required to get access to the actual file that is in the `params[:file]` object.